# align values in table

Tags: tables

I have aligned values in my table the way I want them. However, for some reason this messes up my first row completely. I simply want the labels to be centered above the values. How can I solve this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
\begin{table}[H]
       \centering
       \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
       %\begin{tabular}[width=\textwidth]{l l l l l l}
       \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XSSSSS}
       \hline
       \hline
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{Price} \\
       \hline
          & Cheese & Butter & Milk & Yoghurt & Cream  \\
          \hline
          \hline
          Cheese &  -0.847*** &  0.002 &  -0.068*** & -0.066*** &  -0.031** \\
          
          Butter & 0.017 & -0.996*** &  0.007    &    0.008   &    -0.028\\
          
          Milk  &   -0.224***  &   0.002   &    -0.846***  &   0.029    &    0.016 \\
          
          Yoghurt  &   -0.208*** &    0.018   &     0.052   &    -0.748***  &  -0.033  \\
          
          Cream  &  -0.289*** &   -0.072   &     0.039   &    -0.091***  &  -0.631***  \\
          \hline
          \hline
           \multicolumn{6}{c}{\footnotesize  * p$<$0.1, ** p$<$0.05, *** p$<$0.01}
       \end{tabularx}
       \caption{Second stage estimation of own- and cross-price elasticities}
       \label{cross_price_2d}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Place the contents of the cells in the first row in a set of `{}` in order to horizontally center them with respect to the other contents in the came column.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you want? I had to load `geometry` to prevent the table to overflow into the margin.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{tabularx}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[H]
           \centering
           \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
           \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XSSSSS}
           \hline
           \hline
            &\multicolumn{5}{c}{Price} \\
           \hline
              & {Cheese} & {Butter} & {Milk} & {Yoghurt} & {Cream} \\
              \hline
              \hline
              Cheese & -0.847*** & 0.002 & -0.068*** & -0.066*** & -0.031** \\

              Butter & 0.017 & -0.996*** & 0.007 & 0.008 & -0.028\\

              Milk & -0.224*** & 0.002 & -0.846*** & 0.029 & 0.016 \\

              Yoghurt & -0.208*** & 0.018 & 0.052 & -0.748*** & -0.033 \\

              Cream & -0.289*** & -0.072 & 0.039 & -0.091*** & -0.631*** \\
              \hline
              \hline
               \multicolumn{6}{c}{\footnotesize * p$<$0.1, ** p$<$0.05, *** p$<$0.01}
           \end{tabularx}
           \caption{Second stage estimation of own- and cross-price elasticities}
           \label{cross_price_2d}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\multicolumn{6}{c}{Price} \\ \hline` should probably be replaced with `& \multicolumn{5}{c}{Price} \\ \cline{2-6}`, so that "Price" is centered above the five data columns.

Comment: @Mico: You're right. I  didn't notice this problem. I'll fix it as soon as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to encase the header words "cheese", "butter", etc in curly braces to inform the machinery of the `siunitx` package that they are words, not numbers. (The letter "e", in particular, tends to confuse the `S` column type.)

Second, to conserve horizontal space, you should switch from the unadorned `S` column type, which centers the entire column contents on the decimal markers, to something such as `S[table-format=-1.6]`. I would also issue the instruction `\sisetup{table-align-text-post = false}`, so as to avoid any gaps between the numbers and the trailing asterisks.

Third, I'd replace the `\hline` directives with the line-drawing macros of the booktabs package: `\toprule`, `\cmidrule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule`, and `\addlinespace`. See the code below for an implemenation of this idea. I would also not execute `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{siunitx,tabularx,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{table-align-text-post = false}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} X *{5}{S[table-format=-1.6]} @{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Price} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-6}
    & {Cheese} & {Butter} & {Milk} & {Yoghurt} & {Cream}  \\
    \toprule
    Cheese & -0.847*** &  0.002    & -0.068*** & -0.066*** & -0.031** \\
    
    Butter &  0.017    & -0.996*** &  0.007    &  0.008    & -0.028 \\
    
    Milk   & -0.224*** &  0.002    & -0.846*** &  0.029    &  0.016 \\
    
    Yoghurt& -0.208*** &  0.018    &  0.052    & -0.748*** & -0.033  \\
    
    Cream  & -0.289*** & -0.072    &  0.039    & -0.091*** & -0.631***  \\
    \bottomrule\addlinespace
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{\footnotesize $*\ p<0.1$, ${**}\ p<0.05$, ${*{**}}\ p<0.01$}
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Second stage estimation of own- and cross-price elasticities}
\label{cross_price_2d}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tabularray` package, in standard `article` document:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Second stage estimation of own- and cross-price elasticities},
  label = {cross_price_2d},
 note{} = {*:    $p<0.10$,\quad
           **:   $p<0.05$,\quad
           ***:  $p<0.01$.}
                ]{colsep = 3pt,
                 colspec = {@{} l *{5}{X[c,si={table-format=-1.3{**}}]} @{}},
                 }
    \toprule
        &   \SetCell[c=5]{c}   {{{Price}}}       
                    &           &           &           &                       \\
    \cmidrule{2-6}
        & {{{Cheese}}} 
                    & {{{Butter}}}
                                & {{{Milk}}}
                                            & {{{Yoghurt}}} 
                                                        & {{{Cream}}}           \\
    \midrule
Cheese  & -0.847\TblrNote{***}
                    &  0.002    & -0.068\TblrNote{***} 
                                            & -0.066\TblrNote{***} 
                                                        & -0.031\TblrNote{**}   \\
Butter  &  0.017    & -0.996\TblrNote{***}
                                &  0.007    &  0.008    & -0.028                \\
Milk    & -0.224\TblrNote{***}
                    &  0.002    & -0.846\TblrNote{***}
                                            &  0.029    &  0.016                \\
Yoghurt & -0.208\TblrNote{***}
                    &  0.018    &  0.052    & -0.748\TblrNote{***}
                                                        & -0.033                \\
Cream   & -0.289\TblrNote{***}
                    & -0.072    &  0.039    & -0.091\TblrNote{***}
                                                        & -0.631\TblrNote{***}  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Answer (score 0):

You want to specify `table-format` and to use `tabular*`, not `tabularx`.

I also suggest to use `booktabs` features and to not setting the `\arraystretch` to such a large value as 1.7. Also, avoid `[H]` and let the table float, unless you want to spoil the typographic aspect of your document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% leave the computations to TeX

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  *{5}{S[table-format=-1.3***]}
  @{}
}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{5}{c}{Price} \\
\cmidrule{2-6}
& {Cheese} & {Butter} & {Milk} & {Yoghurt} & {Cream}  \\
\midrule
Cheese &  -0.847*** &  0.002 &  -0.068*** & -0.066*** &  -0.031** \\
Butter & 0.017 & -0.996*** &  0.007    &    0.008   &    -0.028\\
Milk  &   -0.224***  &   0.002   &    -0.846***  &   0.029    &    0.016 \\
Yoghurt  &   -0.208*** &    0.018   &     0.052   &    -0.748***  &  -0.033  \\
Cream  &  -0.289*** &   -0.072   &     0.039   &    -0.091***  &  -0.631***  \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize  * p$<$0.1, ** p$<$0.05, *** p$<$0.01}
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Second stage estimation of own- and cross-price elasticities}
\label{cross_price_2d}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]